# How To Check If Value Is Decreasing Over Months SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

i got revenue over accounts monthly what am looking for is to view earnings for each account in descending order from last decrease
here is the query

```
SELECT account_id,
       monthly_date,
       earnings
FROM accounts_revenue
GROUP BY account_id,
         monthly_date
```

**the data is something like that**

| account_id | monthly_date | earnings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 2017-01-01 | 2000 |
| 55 | 2017-02-01 | 1950 |
| 55 | 2017-10-01 | 2000 |
| 55 | 2018-02-01 | 1500 |
| 55 | 2018-05-01 | 1200 |
| 55 | 2018-12-01 | 3000 |
| 55 | 2019-01-01 | 900 |
| 55 | 2019-02-01 | 810 |
| 55 | 2019-04-01 | 1000 |
| 55 | 2019-05-01 | 600 |
| 55 | 2020-01-01 | 800 |
| 55 | 2020-02-01 | 100 |
| 122 | 2020-01-01 | 800 |
| 122 | 2020-02-01 | 100 |

**so the data should be like that**

| account_id | monthly_date | earnings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 2017-01-01 | 2000 |
| 55 | 2017-02-01 | 1950 |
| 55 | 2018-02-01 | 1500 |
| 55 | 2018-05-01 | 1200 |
| 55 | 2019-01-01 | 900 |
| 55 | 2019-02-01 | 810 |
| 55 | 2019-05-01 | 600 |
| 55 | 2020-02-01 | 100 |
| 122 | 2020-01-01 | 800 |
| 122 | 2020-02-01 | 100 |

any idea how to achieve this ??

Comment: Your results have little to do with the sample data.  It is quite unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Your query should give an error as not all columns are grouped or aggregated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what i need to do is to view account earnings over months (only decreased earning ) so i need to compare current row earning with last decreased value
if current row earning < last decrease earning value then will view it 
else don't view

Comment: @Stu , my query working fine with no error

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ar1.*
FROM accounts_revenue ar1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM accounts_revenue ar2
  WHERE ar2.account_id = ar1.account_id 
    AND ar2.monthly_date < ar1.monthly_date 
    AND ar2.earnings <= ar1.earnings
)
ORDER BY ar1.account_id, ar1.monthly_date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6436b2758c76f423a09232d2a09ee959).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lag()` [window function](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#biwinfunc) and a CTE (Or subquery if you prefer) to filter out rows you don't want:

```sql
WITH revenue AS
  (SELECT account_id, monthly_date, earnings,
          lag(earnings) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY monthly_date) AS prev_earnings
   FROM accounts_revenue)
SELECT account_id, monthly_date, earnings
FROM revenue
WHERE earnings < prev_earnings OR prev_earnings IS NULL
ORDER BY account_id, monthly_date;
```

For efficiency, you'll want an index on `accounts_revenue(account_id, monthly_date)`.

Comment: Or maybe even a covering index on `accounts_revenue(account_id, monthly_date, earnings)`.